# Simple rule does not work

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, rule

Let's see the following example

```
Clear["Global`*"];
d1 = Sqrt[(x + μ)^2 + y^2];
d2 = Sqrt[(x + μ - 1)^2 + y^2];
V = m1/d1 + m2/d2 + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);

rule = {((x + μ)^2 + y^2)^(1/2) -> d1, ((x + μ - 1)^2 + y^2)^(1/2) -> d2};
Vx = D[V, x] /. rule
Vy = D[V, y] /. rule
```

However even if I apply the rule the output is not what I want. I want the two denominators to have the form $d1^3$ and $d2^3$. Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: A way to diagnose why your rules aren't acting on `D[V,x]` and `D[V,y]` is to look at `FullForm[D[V[x]]` and `FullForm[D[V[y]]`, where in the first you will see that the denominator comes from  `Power[Plus[Power[y,2],Power[Plus[-1,x,\[Mu]],2]],Rational[-3,2]]]`, i.e. $(y^2 + (-1 + x + \mu)^2)^{-3/2}$.  In particular, nothing has an exponent of $1/2$.  So either your rules have to be modified to match what will be present, or they need to have parameters, as in the accepted solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use patterns in your replacement rules:

```
Clear["Global`*"];
D1 = Sqrt[(x + μ)^2 + y^2];
D2 = Sqrt[(x + μ - 1)^2 + y^2];
V = m1/D1 + m2/D2 + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);

rules = {((x + μ)^2 + y^2)^n_ ->  d1^(2 n), 
        ((x + μ - 1)^2 + y^2)^n_ -> d2^(2 n)}
Vx = D[V, x] /. rules
Vy = D[V, y] /. rules
```

Explanation: `x^n_ -> t^(2 n)` replaces any power of `x` to `t` raised twice the exponent, therefore `Sqrt[x]^n` gets replaced by `t^n`.

Comment: Nice trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that may be useful is the following:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
f = (x + μ)^2 + y^2;
g = (x + μ - 1)^2 + y^2;
rule = {
   D[d1, z_, NonConstants -> {d1, d2}] :> D[f, z]/2/d1,
   D[d2, z_, NonConstants -> {d1, d2}] :> D[g, z]/2/d2
   };
V = m1/d1 + m2/d2 + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);
D[V, x, NonConstants -> {d1, d2}] /. rule
D[V, y, NonConstants -> {d1, d2}] /. rule
```

The motivation for this approach is to make the replacement rule a little more general and to take advantage of the `NonConstants` option of the derivative function.  To understand this approach, we consider the expression

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
V = m1/d1 + m2/d2 + 1/2*(x^2 + y^2);
D[V, x, NonConstants -> {d1, d2}]
```

which gives us $\partial_x V$ in terms of `D[d1,x,NonConstants -> {d1,d2}]`.  We write our rule to express $\partial_x d_1$ in terms of `d` as follows

```
D[d1, z_, NonConstants -> {d1, d2}] :> D[f, z]/2/d1
```

There are several things to note in the above rule.  First, it uses variable `f`, which is explained in the next paragraph.  Second, is uses the delayed rule function `:>`.  Third, it assumes $d_1=\sqrt{f}$ so that $\partial_x d_1=(\partial_x f)/(2d_1)$.  Fourth, we are using `z` to name the argument of the derivative function, so the rule will work for $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$, but `z` must be an undefined symbol.

So, to summarize, this approach defines `f` and `g`, the arguments of the `Sqrt` function, creates rules for taking the derivatives of `d1` and `d2`, and applies the rules to the derivative of V.

The advantage of this approach is that we can change `f` and `g` without affecting the rest of the code, which  could sometimes be desirable.  We can, in fact, change or define `f` and `g` anywhere before the rule is applied.  That is, we can define the rule first, take the derivative of $V$, then define `f` and`g` before applying the rule.

Another delayed rule that may be handy is `r2 = {d1 :> Sqrt[f], d2 :> Sqrt[g]}`.